# Broken ImageMagick configuration

Tags: linux, perl, delegates, imagemagick

Yesterday I decided I wanted to install Perl-Magick to do some scripting on my images. I seem to have broken ImageMagick's delegates and created multiple versions. I'm not entirely sure... I'm fairly new to linux. I traced back my command paths as best as I could and I will try to guide you along what I did.

Before deciding to install Perl-Magick (from source), I had version 6.7.7 of ImageMagick and it worked great. 
I pretty much followed the instructions here to install Perl-Magick.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

```
        tar xczf ImageMagick.tar.gz
        ./configure -with-perl
        make
        sudo make install
```

The make had an error, stating that I was missing lbperl (I think that's what it was. I don't have any output logs.)
So for whatever reason I thought moving to the imagemagick directory and trying again might fix it.

```
        cd ImageMagick-6.8.9-5
        ./configure -with-perl
        make
        sudo make install
```

Make failed again so I thought moving the imagemagick directory to another directory might fix it.

```
        mv ImageMagick-6.8.9-5 /usr/share
        sudo su
        perl -e "use Image::Magick; print Image::Magick->QuantumDepth"
```

The test command didn't work. Tried messing around a bit more.

```
        sudo ldconfig usr/local/lib
        ./configure -with-perl
         sudo make install
        cd PerlMagick
```

At this point I realized that there were some errors when I tried to convert a PNG. I think the primary error being that the delegate code for PNG was no longer there. 
Tried a bunch of ways to get rid of it so I could reinstall it clean.

```
        sudo apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick
        sudo apt-get remove imagemagick
        rm -rf ImageMagick-6.8.9-5
        sudo apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick
        sudo ldconfig usr/local/lib
        sudo apt-get --purge remove imagemagick
        sudo apt-get install imagemagick
        sudo apt-get --purge remove imagemagick
        sudo apt-get install imagemagick
        sudo apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick
```

At this point I was pretty frustrated so I asked a senior programmer if he could help me figure it out. He suggested doing the make again with a make uninstall.

```
        tar xczf ImageMagick.tar.gz
        ./configure -with-perl
        sudo make uninstall
```

Discovered that PerlMagick doesn't support "uninstall." (How the heck am I supposed to remove it?)

```
        sudo make install

        sudo apt-get install libperl-dev
        sudo make install
```

The core of the issue for my work purposes comes down to the fact that I can't do anything with PNGs.. so I got the png lib and extracted the tar. Still no luck. :(

```
        tar xvfz libpng-1.6.12.tar.gz
```

Today I went to my /usr/local/lib directory and found this:

```
        Jul  2 15:34 ImageMagick-6.8.9
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickCore-6.Q16.a
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickCore-6.Q16.so -> libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2 -> libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickWand-6.Q16.a
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickWand-6.Q16.la
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickWand-6.Q16.so -> libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2 -> libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
        Jul  2 15:34 libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
        Jul  2 15:34 perl
        Jul  2 15:34 pkgconfig
```

I don't know if that's supposed to be there... I have this development environment that I can connect to which also has imagemagick installed and I didn't find anything like this in the same directory.

Also, I did a dpkg --list | less and found this:

```
        ii  imagemagick                  8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
        ii  imagemagick-common           8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
```

Also, I checked out my /usr/libls - and I don't have anything for ImageMagick-6.8.9 but I do have a directory for ImageMagick-6.7.7 but all it has is three XML files, "english.xml", "french.xml", "locale.xml." I would assume that means I'm missing all of the configuration files. Is there no easy way for me to completely remove this mess and get a pre-configured version of imagemagick?

One more bit of information. I took a look at usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.8.9/config-Q16/configure.xml and am missing the the png delegate. Tried configuring it with ./configure --with-png. Still nothing.

Okay. I think that's everything.

EDIT: Here's the results of the config run

```
              Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yes     yes
              Static libraries  --enable-static=yes     yes
              Module support    --with-modules=no       no
              GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=yes       yes
              Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=16 16
              High Dynamic Range Imagery
              --enable-hdri=no      no

              Install documentation:        yes

              Delegate Configuration:
              BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes        no
              Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no     no
              Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default  none
              DJVU              --with-djvu=yes     no
              DPS               --with-dps=yes      no
              FFTW              --with-fftw=yes     no
              FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes      no
              FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes       no
              FreeType          --with-freetype=yes     no
              GhostPCL          None                pcl6 (unknown)
              GhostXPS          None                gxps (unknown)
              Ghostscript       None                gs (9.10)
              Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default  /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/
              Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=no     no
              Graphviz          --with-gvc=no       
              JBIG              --with-jbig=yes     no
              JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes     no
              JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=     
              LCMS v1           --with-lcms=yes     no
              LCMS v2           --with-lcms2=yes        no
              LQR               --with-lqr=yes      no
              LTDL              --with-ltdl=yes     no
              LZMA              --with-lzma=yes     no
              Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes no (failed tests)
              OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes      no
              OpenJP2           --with-openjp2=yes      no
              PANGO             --with-pango=yes        no
              PERL              --with-perl=no      no
              PNG               --with-png=yes      no
              RSVG              --with-rsvg=no      no
              TIFF              --with-tiff=yes     no
              WEBP              --with-webp=yes     no
              Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=    none
              WMF               --with-wmf=no       no
              X11               --with-x=           yes
              XML               --with-xml=yes      no
              ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes     no

              X11 Configuration:
                    X_CFLAGS        = 
                    X_PRE_LIBS      = -lSM -lICE
                    X_LIBS          = 
                    X_EXTRA_LIBS    = 

              Options used to compile and link:
                PREFIX          = /usr/local
                EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
                VERSION         = 6.8.9
                CC              = gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99
                CFLAGS          = -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -march=corei7-avx -fexceptions -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
                CPPFLAGS        = -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
                PCFLAGS         = 
                DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
                LDFLAGS         = 
                LIBS            = 
                CXX             = g++
                CXXFLAGS        = -pthread
                FEATURES        = DPC OpenMP
                DELEGATES       = mpeg ps x
```

Comment: This may help? http://sigstp.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/imagemagick-with-perlbrew.html?spref=tw

Comment: To be honest, I don't even need the perl component anymore. I just want to restore imagemagick. Thank you, though.

Comment: I presume that you're on Unbuntu/Debian (apt package manager). Are you also using the system perl? If so, there's a `perlmagick` package available.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the imagemagick forums I was able to find an answer.

I went into the directory containing the most recent version of IM that I had installed (6.8.9-5) and did a "make uninstall" from there.

My machine still had the older version of IM (6.7.7) which was properly configured. I think what went wrong is that I installed the latest version of IM and did not first do a ./configure. I went straight to ./configure --with-perl which probably didn't have all the configurations for image formats.

I think if I were to redo the latest version install and configure it properly, it would work just fine. 6.7.7 is fine for my purposes right now!

Comment: And, did it work? I can't seem to get it working: http://askubuntu.com/questions/745660/imagemagick-png-delegate-install-problems